# How to control the background opacity of progress dialog in Roku scene graph?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I am using main.brs code to show the progress loading dialog . If i use this code for progress dialog then its default background is occupying complete screen. here i want to show only progress loading animation and background should be little transparent. could anyone please help on this.

**'Main.brs**

```
ShowLoading = CreateObject("roSGScreen")
ShowLoading.CreateScene("ProgressDialogExample")
ShowLoading.show()
```

**'ProgressDialogExample.Xml**

```
<component name = "ProgressDialogExample" extends = "Scene">

  <script type = "text/brightscript" >
    <![CDATA[
    sub init()
        progressdialog = createObject("roSGNode", "ProgressDialog")
        progressdialog.title = "Loading..."
        m.top.dialog = progressdialogs
        m.top.setFocus(true)
    end sub 
    ]]>
  </script>
</component>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special node class called `BusySpinner` that used inside `ProgressDialog`. You can use it with a label to get a progress dialog with a transparent background.
Add the following code into the file ProgressDialogExample.Xml:

```
<children>
    <Group>
        <BusySpinner 
            id="spinner"
            translation="[570, 300]"
            control="start"
            clockwise="true"
            spinInterval="2" />
        <Label
            id="lblLoding"
            horizAlign="center"
            text="Loading"
            color="0x6c3b97ff"
            font="font:LargeBoldSystemFont"
            translation="[620, 300]" />
    </Group>
</children>
```

Also, add an image to the folder "images" that will be used as a loading image.
Then, in Main.brs add the following code:

```
spinner = m.top.FindNode("spinner")
spinner.poster.uri="pkg:/images/loader.png"
```

Comment: Thanks roman for your help. but i want to remove the default grey background and make it transparent so that my app screen is visible in the background.
Could you please help me on this...

Comment: ProgressDialog is a kind of Dialog. I am not sure if it will be possible to remove it's background. You should use a custom solution (something like I wrote in this post).

Comment: I tried, but it is occupying complete screen. at least is it possible to decrease height and width of that default background screen?

Comment: I think it is not possible to change it's height or width.